# The meaning of "Having done my homework I will go home."

Tags: grammar, absolute-clauses

> Having done my homework I will go home.

What does *having* mean in this sentence?

Comment: The cited construction is common (though a little formal) in the past tense *(Having done my work I went home)*, but much less likely in relation to *future* events, where most people would say *After I have done A, I will do B* (or *I'll do B once I've done A*, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

The word 'having' in this sentence means that I have done my homework, therefore I can carry out the specified action (go home).

Having done/Having finished is an example of a ***perfect participle***, indicating you have completed the past action, and can carry out the second action.

Answer (score 1):

[Having done](http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/participleperfect.html) is the perfect participle and indicates a completed action.

> You did your homework and now you will go home.

Answer (score 1):

*[Have](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/have)* can be either a main verb (with several meanings, one of them is to posses something) or an **[auxiliary verb](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/auxiliary-verb)** which is the case here. It doesn't have any meaning on its own; it is a part of grammatical construction called the **[perfect participle](http://www.englishtenses.com/perfect_participle).**

This construction is built with *have* in the -ing form + past participle. It is used to show that the first action was completed before the second.

---

At first I thought that it would sound more natural if the perfect participle was used with another clause in the past (not future) but I found [this example](https://books.google.rs/books?id=IC7LMkPUmt0C&pg=PA72&dq=%22having+done%22+%22I+will%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZGxgVbGbI8u7ygPirIGQBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22having%20done%22%20%22I%20will%22&f=false) published by University of Chicago Press (which I assume is a reputable publisher) and [some other examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22having+done%22+%22I+will%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22having+done%22+%22I+will%22&tbm=bks&start=40) so I stand corrected.